# Passport not logging in | Think due to strategy's

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a pretty simple application that is just an auth service and a profile page with a logout button at this point. I am trying to signup a user, who is redirected to `/profile` and then I logout. All of this works fine. I also have a verification email in there too but that is currently besides the point.

My issue is that when I go to log into the site it gives me no error messages, nothing, just redirects me to `/login` which is what my passport strategy's meant to do if there is an error.

Can anyone spot an error in my code that would cause me not to log into the site? I have included what I think are the important parts of my application.

**app.js**

```
// PASSPORT CONFIGURATION
require('./controllers/passport')(passport);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./routes/index.js')(app, passport);
```

**passport.js login strategy**

```
passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'email',
      passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {

      User.findOne({ 'email' :  email },
        function(err, user) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          if (!user){
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'User not found'));
          }
          user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
            }
            if (isMatch) {
              // Make sure the user has been verified
              if (!user.isVerified) return done (null, false, req.flash('error', 'Your account has not been verified.' ));
              var time = 14 * 24 * 3600000;
              req.session.cookie.maxAge = time; //2 weeks
              req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + time);
              req.session.touch();
              return done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'Successfully logged in.'));
            } else {
              return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Invalid Password'));
            }

          });
        }
      );
    })
  );
```

**login route**

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', 
    failureRedirect : '/login', 
    failureFlash : true 
}));
```

**user.js model**

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    role: String,
    avatar: String,

    isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField : 'email' });
UserSchema.plugin(timestamps);

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;

  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this solved it but it did... I added in my auth middleware that checks if a user should be able to access the page or not and now I can log in. Here is my middleware that checks it.

**middleware**

```
exports.isUnauthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  }

  res.redirect('/');
};
```

Then I just required it and updated my post route to be

**post login route**

```
app.post('/login', isUnauthenticated, passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', 
        failureRedirect : '/login', 
        failureFlash : true 
    }));
```